# How to prevent "Swapping" of "Staged" Azure Websites from logging users out?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have deployed a MVC3, Membership Services, .NET4, C#, Razor, EF4.1, SQL Azure Web application into Azure using Azure Websites(Standard).

I have been experimenting with the new "staging" feature where one can "swap" in an upgraded web application. Very good. What we would really like to do is to upgrade code without interfering with the end user ie Continuous integration of small fixes. However we have noticed that a "Swap" logs users out which is not ideal. I suspect this is to do with authentication cookies being lost after the "swap" so the session cannot authenticate resulting in the users being returned to the login page. Is there a way around this? The only thought I have had is to somehow persist the "essentials" in the database.

Thoughts appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set up a machineKey in your web.config?

Comment: Thanks for this. There is no reference to "machineKey" in any files in my solution. Should there be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your "stage" application is on another instance, you will need to have a matching machineKey across the two applications.  Add the following to your web.config, so that a machineKey is not auto generated.

```
<machineKey
    validationKey="052851E2D519231BE84E455B4C4A9FBC0CAC53B8FE7BBA1917FC296ACE6F41832383347EAEC498F40978DDD3374E7A666AFD0ADC1084A9E48B1B40ADC918C9A6"
    decryptionKey="7077D8F4C273E3FC5CE296F3B74897ACECF055F9BA01565372EE87B8746DE50F"
    validation="SHA1" 
    decryption="AES" />
```

Replace the keys with your own.  You can generate them through IIS or [here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey).  You can also change the encryption and decryption algorithms if you so choose.

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this. It will make a big difference. You learn something everyday.